# Android Gmail app - can't download some attachments - Nexus 5

Tags: gmail, attachments, download-manager

The problem is that I can download some attachments, but some not. I usually cannot download zip attachments that are forwarded to me. I cleared cache and data of the Download Manager, but that didn't help. Any ideas?

Edit: I use Gmail app for my business POP3 account.

Comment: You might need to install an app that registers as a handler for `.zip` files.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that, but I think every email app should let me download any attachment, no matter what file type the attachment is.

Comment: Are you not able to download the attachements? or Open the Downloaded Attachements..?

Comment: Download. When I click on the download icon, it does nothing, like a button without a function.

Comment: When I click save to drive, it shows saving, but actually takes infinite time and does nothing.

Comment: Have you tried clearing the cache of Gmail app? Restart you phone and Check once again. And are you able to download something from the browser to make sure the Download Manager works properly?

Comment: What apps "should" do is not relevant to what Gmail *does* do.

Comment: Just tried that, didn't work.